# Scroll on DOM based generated PDF

Tags: pdf, dom, kendo-ui

Hi This is my first question to stackoverflow. In my project we have requirement to generate the PDF based on DOM. There were multiple requirement and we used Kendo for this. PDF was generated from Bootstrap pages and many UI issue was there as bootsrap3 is not officially support the print version. There were overlapping and table width issue, content was going off the screen due to Boostrap offset classes all of them are sorted now. One more task client ask that can we apply scroll to pdf were we have grid and lots of column. On browser everyone know we can manage it by applying horizontal scroll and user can see the rest of the data by scrolling it.

As per my experience I don't see this kind of example but still asking is there any possibility to implement the scroll for generated PDF where we have grid with lots of column?

Answer (score 0):

PDF content layout is static and there are no scrollbars for items, such as tables within.  So, no possibility.

When a grid is too wide you have to decide how to split up the layout of the grid for 'printout' pages.  For example, suppose your grid needs six pages to fit in a pdf

The pages in the pdf could be from this row-wise layout

```
A wide grid
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
+---+---+---+
```

or this column-wise layout

```
A wide grid
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
+---+---+---+
```

Which ever you choose, the content in a pdf reader will look like

```
A wide grid (direction-wise)
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
... pages 2 to 5 ...
+---+
| 6 |
+---+
```

If the content is widely variant it might be easier to sell the client on receiving Excel content instead of PDF, versus trying to code your own grid to pdf layout engine.

If the web page is only the grid, you could also consider using the spreadsheet component, which has a pdf download feature which renders column-wise.

Comment: Thank for suggestion, was buys with other implementation.